# How to update the existing .plist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, plist

How to update the existing plist with info? I have simple dictionary with strings. Here is my save method:

```
#define DOCUMENTS [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject]

- (IBAction)saveData:(id)sender {
    NSMutableDictionary *data = [NSMutableDictionarydictionaryWithObjects:@[self.textFieldOne.text, self.textFieldTwo.text, self.textFieldThree.text] forKeys:@[@"Key1", @"Key2", @"Key3"]];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSData *dataToPlist = [NSPropertyListSerialization dataWithPropertyList:data format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 options:0 error:&error];
    NSString *path = [DOCUMENTS stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"userData.plist"];
    [dataToPlist writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
}
```

So, it's OK when I call this method from Class 1, but when I want to update this plist with other info from Class 2 – it overwrites old info with new info. What I should do to update the existing plist with new info from other classes?

Comment: I assume "in my application", rather than "in Xcode"? Xcode has nothing to do with this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to load the existing plist into an `NSDictionary` or `NSArray` (as appropriate), then update the data with the additional data, and finally write out the updated data to the plist file.

Answer (score 1):

Basically the existing one you have to read into dictionary using dictionarywithcontentsfile method and then on the basis of your requirement use setobjecwt method into dictionary and then write to plist. So that old value will be retain there and you can updates new as well.